# Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider extension not found

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2019

How to in install Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider tool in visual studio 2019? Its not showing up in installed extensions or search results.
I am using

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.7.6
[This is my project type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJtpt.png)

Comment: What type of project are you trying to use the tool with? Please refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide

Comment: Console application with dot net framework.

Answer (score 1):

The WCF Web Service Reference option is just applicable to projects created using the following project templates:

Visual C# > .NET Core

Visual C# > .NET Standard

Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Core Web Application

Comment: Can you please provide a link how to install the extension?